# error: package R does not exist - generated fragment directions file after Gradle update

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Using the Android Studio Gradle upgrade wizard, I:

1. Upgraded Android Gradle Plugin from version 7.1.2 to version 7.2.0
2. Upgraded Gradle from version from version 7.2 to version 7.3.3
3. Moved package from Android manifest to build files at Android Studio's recommendation (“Declaration of a project's namespace using the package attribute of the Android manifest is deprecated in favour of a namespace declaration in build files.”)

However, after building my app, I get the following error in one of my generated fragment direction files (`OverviewFragmentDirections.java`).

```
error: package R does not exist
```

I'm using the following dependencies related to navigation.

- `androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin` (version 2.4.1)
- `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx` (version 2.4.2)
- `androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx` (version 2.4.2)

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Try Invalidating Cache/Restart and then go to the imports of the file and remove previous import of com.yourpackagme.R and then try to import R again.

Comment: @AtulYadav I tried invalidating but I can't remove the import. `OverviewFragmentDirections.java` is a generated fragment direction file. Invalidating did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating your navigation dependencies to version [`2.5.2`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.5.2) will resolve the error.

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.2")
        ...
    }
}
```

`build.gradle (:app)`

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2"

    ...
}
```